# Django static files cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, css, django, path, static

I'm getting the following error at 'line 316, in listdir for entry in os.scandir(path)' when running collectstatic in Django:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path
> specified:
> 'C:\\Users\\rutha_000\\Documents\\DjangoProjects\\jarvis\\static'

My stylesheet is located in

> C:\Users\rutha_000\Documents\DjangoProjects\jarvis\static\jarvis\css\

And my settings file looks like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

File locations as follows:

Django projects
jarvis
app
static
app
css
stylesheet.css
jarvis
settings.py
manage.py

Thanks

Comment: Where is your static folder and your settings.py file?

Comment: Edited above if that answers your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

in `settings.py` with

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/static'),
]
```

Hope that works.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\\Users\\rutha_000\\Documents\\DjangoProjects\\jarvis\\static`

represents the string

`C:\Users\rutha_000\Documents\DjangoProjects\jarvis\static`

As can be seen,

```
>>> print('C:\\Users\\rutha_000\\Documents\\DjangoProjects\\jarvis\\static')
C:\Users\rutha_000\Documents\DjangoProjects\jarvis\static
```

so nothing's wrong with `\\`

Comment: Oh woops - any ideas why I'm still getting a FileNotFoundError?

Comment: which line of code the error (`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\rutha_000\\Documents\\DjangoProjects\\jarvis\\static`) occurs?

Comment: line 316, in listdir for entry in os.scandir(path)

Comment: where do `path` come from?

Answer (score 0):

" In scripts, backslashes in a file path must always be escaped on windows. ". That is why double backslashes.
Is the path to `settings.py` is:
`C:\Users\rutha_000\Documents\DjangoProjects\jarvis\jarvis\settings.py` ? I think this might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

1. STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'base/static'),

make sure it is in your app